# How to create a local user account with a PrincipalSource of MicrosoftAccount via Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, user-accounts, microsoft-account

In Windows 11/Server 2022 is it possible to create a user with a `PrincipalSource` of `MicrosoftAccount` via Powershell?

The `New-LocalUser` [cmdlet documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) discusses the `PrincipalSource` property but doesn't actually list a flag to set it; the only way I've found to create a user that signs in with a Microsoft account (and thus has a `PrincipalSource` of `MicrosoftAccount`) is via the GUI in the settings app.